# Android slide-up and slide-down animation

Tags: android-animation

I'm running slide-up and slide-down animation for header and footer view for first time.

It is sliding up and after touch event and it's sliding down but after that as i set a delay of 2 seconds.

It's not animating. In animation listner i set view. Gone in animation end. but if remove it ,every thing is working fine.

i am confused whether i am doing something wrong. I know many threads are there on stackoverflow, but ,dont know my logic is wrong or something else s wrong.Or else if is there any other way of doing this.
any help will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Instead view animation ,I have used ObjectAnimator.This solves my animation issue.
Here in ObjectAnimator's callback methods i set setVisibility() to GONE, and it Works!!:)